# Variance of a time series fitted to an ARIMA model

Tags: r, variance, arima

I think this is a basic question, but maybe I am confusing the concepts.

Suppose I fit an ARIMA model to a time series using, for example, the function auto.arima() in the R forecast package. The model assumes constant variance. How do I obtain that variance? Is it the variance of the residuals?

If I use the model for forecasting, I know that it gives me the conditional mean. I'd like to know the (constant) variance as well.

Thank you.

Bruno

---

### Update 1:

I added some code below. The variance given by `sigma2` isn't close to the one calculated from the fitted values. I'm still wondering if `sigma2` is the right option. See figure below for time series plot.

```
demand.train <- c(10.06286, 9.56286, 10.51914, 12.39571, 14.72857, 15.89429, 15.89429, 17.06143, 
              17.72857, 16.56286, 14.23000, 15.39571, 13.06286, 15.39571, 15.39571, 16.56286,
              16.21765, 15.93449, 14.74856, 14.46465, 15.38132)
timePoints.train <- c("Q12006", "Q22006", "Q32006", "Q12007", "Q22007", "Q32007", "Q12008", "Q22008",
                      "Q32008", "Q12009", "Q22009", "Q32009", "Q12010", "Q22010", "Q32010", "Q12011",
                      "Q22011", "Q32011", "Q12012", "Q22012", "Q32012")

plot(1:length(timePoints.train), demand.train, type="o", xaxt="n", ylim=c(0, max(demand.train) + 2), 
     ylab="Demand", xlab="Quadrimestre")

title(main="Time Series Demand of Product C", font.main=4)
axis(1, at=1:length(timePoints.train), labels=timePoints.train)
box()

### ARIMA Fit
library(forecast)

# Time series
demandts.freq <- 3
demandts.train <- ts(demand.train, frequency=demandts.freq, start=c(2006, 1))

# Model fitting
demandts.train.arima <- auto.arima(demandts.train, max.p=10, max.q=10, max.P=10, max.Q=10, max.order=10)
print(demandts.train.arima)
summary(demandts.train.arima)
demandts.train.arima.fit <- fitted(demandts.train.arima)

# Forecast ARIMA (conditional means)
demandts.arima.forecast <- forecast(demandts.train.arima, h = 3, level=95)
print(demandts.arima.forecast)

# Constant variance from ARIMA
demandts.arima.var <- demandts.train.arima$sigma2
print(demandts.arima.var)

# Variance from fitted values
print(var(demandts.train.arima.fit))
```

[image: Time Series Plot]

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert but I can say:

`autoarima()` will attempt to fit a integrated auto regressive moving average process to your data. Once the data is appropriately differenced and the auto regressive component and the moving average components are removed you are left with residuals with a variance. In R this is the `sigma2` in the `arima` object. Usually I don't look at sigma2 until I first examine the ACF plots carefully.

A quick read on using `forecast` package can be found at: 
http://otexts.com/fpp/8/7/

Comment: So as you see the sigma2 is different from the variance of your x variable, also it is different from the variance of the residuals: `var(residuals(demandts.train.arima))`.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I meant to have calculated `var` of the fitted values. Still, it's different from `sigma2` and the variance of the residuals.

Comment: I think the variance of the fitted values is is: var(demandts.train.arima.fit) which is also different

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, sigma2 is the constant variance the model assumes, and it is the variance for the innovations or random shocks (uncorrelated zero mean random variables) that the model uses behind the scenes. An ARIMA model is one where the current random variable $X_t$ can be written as the sum of a linear filter of the previous $X_{t-h}, h>0$ (the AR part, and also the I (order of differencing) if it has unit roots in a certain sense), and a linear filter of the random shocks $Z_{t-j}, j\geq 0$ in which the coefficient of $Z_t$ is 1 (the MA part, not counting $Z_t$ itself). These random shocks are the ones that have to have a common variance.